# Deserialize Object List Json

Tags: c#, json, parsing, serialization, request

I'm new in C# and I want to get a JSON from my app in heroku. Before I did it in javascript with no problems but I'm triying to do it in C# now.
My code is:

```
namespace FirstApp
{
    public class AOA
    {
        public Data data { get; set; }

        public static void Main()
        {
            var json = string.Empty;
            var aoa = new List<AOA>();
            try
            {
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"http://beautyglam.herokuapp.com/aoa/eyeliner?page=1");
                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);

                json = reader.ReadToEnd();
                aoa = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<AOA>>(json);

                Console.WriteLine("DATOS");
                Console.WriteLine(json);
                Console.WriteLine(aoa[0].data);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Errorrr: " + e);
            }
        }
    }

    public class Data
    {
        public string category { get; set; }
        public int pages { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int? price { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string img { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The returned json is something like:

```
[{"category":"AOA Eye Liner","pages":0},{"name":"AOA Starlet Eyeliner- Spotlight","price":150,"id":"751612657678","img":"//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0882/6874/products/AOA-164-MAIN_large.jpg?v=1539192189"},{"name":"AOA Starlet Eyeliner- Hollywood","price":150,"id":"751612592142","img":"//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0882/6874/products/AOA-166-MAIN_large.jpg?v=1539192156"},{"name":"AOA Starlet Eyeliner- Fame","price":150,"id":"751612559374","img":"//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0882/6874/products/AOA-169-MAIN_large.jpg?v=1539192087"},{"name":"AOA Starlet Eyeliner- Superstar","price":150,"id":"751612526606","img":"//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0882/6874/products/AOA-167-MAIN_large.jpg?v=1539192203"},{"name":"AOA Starlet Eyeliner- Paparazzi","price":150,"id":"751612461070","img":"//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0882/6874/products/AOA-165-MAIN_large.jpg?v=1539192338"},{"name":"AOA Starlet Eyeliner- Golden Girl","price":150,"id":"751612329998","img":"//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0882/6874/products/AOA-168-MAIN_large.jpg?v=1539192127"},{"name":"AOA Wonder Liquid Liner - Black","price":150,"id":"194917793806","img":"//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0882/6874/products/AOA-036-1_large.jpg?v=1522944978"},{"name":"AOA Wonder Liquid Liner - Dark Brown","price":150,"id":"194917335054","img":"//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0882/6874/products/AOA-037-1_large.jpg?v=1522944879"}]
```

I want to use it like in Javascript, for example:

```
aoa[0].name;
```

Comment: What does the code do now? What do you want it to do instead?

Comment: Your code seems fine (except i would suggest you to use `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client` nuget package to do this a lot more simpler). What do you think is wrong with you code? Is there any exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class representation of your json structure is not valid for your example. Also, your json structure needs to be parsed with some special deserializer because it is not contains consist values.

You have an array of json object but they are not have same type.

You need 3 classes which one represents category and pages, one represents name,price,id,img and one for the root which containts those two classes.

Here is what it should look like:

```
class RootObj {
    public Category category { get; set; }
    public List<Detail> details { get; set; }
}

class Category {
    public string category { get; set; }
    public int pages { get; set; }
}

class Detail {
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int price { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string img { get; set; }
}
```

Here is custom deserializer:

```
class CustomObjectConverter<T> : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JArray array = JArray.Load(reader);

        RootObj result = new RootObj();

        result.category = array[0].ToObject<Category>();
        array.RemoveAt(0);
        result.details = array.ToObject<List<Detail>>();

        return result;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(RootObj));
    }
}
```

Main :

```
string jsonText = File.ReadAllText("json.txt");

var deserializer = new JsonSerializerSettings();
deserializer.Converters.Add(new CustomObjectConverter<RootObj>());

var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObj>(jsonText, deserializer);
```

Now you can access the properties as :

```
Console.WriteLine(result.category.category);
```

Output is :

```
AOA Eye Liner
```

You can customize it according to your use cases.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm new using this and I'm getting a little confused in C#. I will learn how to do it.